# Orientation Change not Grabbing Correct layout

Tags: android

I have two layout files, one for landscape (layout-land) and one for portrait (layout-port).  When I run my application the correct layout is grabbed initially dependent upon how I am holding my phone. If I am holding landscape, landscape is grabbed and visa versa.  BUT, once I initially launch my application, if I change orientation the first layout grabbed at launch is used when switching orientation.

How do I get Android to changed layout xml per orientation change after initial launch of applicaiton?

In my manifest I have android:configChanges="orientation/keyboardHidden"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify configChanges in the manifest for an activity, the activity has to handle the events by itself. Either do the required layout change in the activity or remove the configChanges in the manifest.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

Comment: I removed orientation from my android:configChanges in my manifest and now it handles.  Now that I have a better understanding there I actually need to do this programatically because I had this in my manifest to ensure dialog boxes remained when switching orientations.

Comment: Yeah, I recognize that "problem" :)

Do you use showDialog(int) in the activity or just show() on a dialog-object? The former allows handling for dialogs when rotating

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ShowingADialog

Comment: So, if stick with configChanges="orientation", how do I trigger a layout change?